# Android Studio API Level 28: Rotating emulator does not rotate the app contents or device UI

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, screen-rotation

**Foreword**. I know this question has been asked several times in the past, but none of the solutions have actually worked for me. It's also been several years since a similar question has been asked (according to a time-filtered Google search), so most of the older answers are outdated. If there's any way I can edit the question to be clearer, please let me know.

**Problem**. When I click either of the rotation buttons, the emulator itself rotates, but the user interface and app contents do not get redrawn accordingly, such that I have to tilt my head (defeating the purpose of rotating the device).

**Specifications**

- Android Studio 3.2
- Android SDK 9.0 (Pie)
- Nexus 5X API 28 (I've tried other devices, but the issue persists)
- I do not have any Android Manifest orientation attributes set

**Screenshots**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Make sure auto-rotate is enabled on the virtual device. Pull down the notification bar and look for the Auto-rotate toggle and turn it on. Or, go into Settings->Display->Advanced and make sure Auto-rotate screen is turned on.

Comment: You're welcome!  I had to manually enable auto-rotate on my Pixel 3, so I figured the Pie AVD must have the same problem.

Comment: Wow, never thought about that!

Comment: Thank you Greg. I found the same problem with the Android 10 emulator. It took me a while to figure out what you were referring to as I thought it was an AVD config. My Pixel 2 just got updated to 10 today so I wanted to update AVD. For those equally confused Greg referred to the emulated phone under Settings.